# Google Cloud Datastore - cannot read property 'createInsecure' of undefined

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, grpc, google-cloud-platform

> DataStore version 1.2.0

This is the code I use to return a new Datastore for live and test versions from within a function:

```
const Datastore = require('@google-cloud/datastore')
...
let localDatastore = Datastore({
  projectId: '<<replaced-project-id>>',
  apiEndpoint: 'localhost:8081'
})

return isLive() ? Datastore() : localDatastore
```

I receive this error message on both Google App Engine and when ran locally:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'createInsecure' of undefined
at new Datastore (<removed path>/node_modules/@google-cloud/datastore/src/index.js:400:45)
at Datastore (<removed path>/node_modules/@google-cloud/datastore/src/index.js:366:12)
```

This is the line it complains about:

```
this.options.sslCreds = grpc.credentials.createInsecure();
```

It seemed to be working before I removed, then re-installed my node_modules. These are my  dependencies:

```
"@google-cloud/datastore": "^1.2.0",
"bluebird": "^3.4.7",
"joi": "^10.6.0",
"lodash": "^4.17.4",
"moment": "^2.17.1",
"shortid": "^2.2.6",
"ticketbuddy-library": "file:../ticketbuddy-library",
"uuid": "^3.0.1"
```

But my git history doesn't show any changes made to my package.json, or to the codebase to return a new Datastore.

Any help as to why I'm getting this error would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This looks like a bug in the google cloud datastore library. I think they would find it helpful if you file an issue with their GitHub repository.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that I have found is to set the DataStore version to 1.1.0 in the package.json file:

`"@google-cloud/datastore": "1.1.0"`

Answer (score 0):

At the official GitHub [issue tracker](https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-datastore/issues/15) there is a solution that goes like this:

> I think this line is getting us in trouble here. I believe this
>   returns a grpc wrapper and not an actual grpc instance. I think we can
>   do this however

```
var grpc = require('google-gax').grpc().grpc;
```

Try running previous command before the line that give you problem.